# Capistrano mysql2 error command denied to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, mysql2

When i deploy with Capistrano it runs rake db:migrate and then i get this following error:

```
rake aborted!
DEBUG [42a60046]    
DEBUG [42a60046]    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: CREATE command denied to user 'stageapp'@'localhost' for table 'schema_migrations': CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Just read: CREATE command denied to user 'stageapp'@'localhost' for table 'schema_migrations'.

Comment: Yeah i read that but how do i solve it?

Comment: Give the rights to create table in your mySQL server for `stageapp` ! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: `mysql> grant all on stageapp.* to 'you_db_user'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 0):

Comment by Зелёный was the solution

```
    "mysql> grant all on stageapp.* to 'you_db_user'@'localhost';"
```

Comment: While this will work, for security reasons, I would not suggest doing something like this on a production machine. Preferably, just give the permissions that user would need in order to do what it needs to.

Comment: And how would you recommend doing that, which commands. I am using rails on a ubuntu vps.